# Heroku not displaying background image/fonts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, asset-pipeline

I'm running into a bit of an issue on one of my first rails projects. 
Locally, in development, my website is displaying perfectly. Fonts are being loaded correctly and the background image is displaying on every page. On Heroku however, the fonts do not appear, nor does the background image.

I have tried running the following commands
`RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile`
`RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:clobber assets:precompile`
`RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:clean assets:precompile`
`heroku run rake assets:precompile`
`heroku run rake assets:clobber assets:precompile`
`heroku run rake assets:clean assets:precompile`

None of these commands changed the way the app was displaying, I also made sure to clear cookies before each attempt and even view in incognito; everything to no avail.


I also attempted to change how the background image was being introduced into the project.
* I changed the custom css file to end with a css.scss
* I altered the css call from `background:` to `background-image:`
... This caused the background image to fail to load locally as well
*I altered the css call from 
 `url('../img/bg.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;` to 
`image-url('../img/bg.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;`
... Again all this did was cause the image to not be loaded locally
I tried doing a combination of those two, again, to no avail.
I have both my css files and my image files located in the appropriate folders inside of the app/assets directory. The files are actually showing up inside of the public/assets folder as well, but still, the website does not display the fonts nor the background image.
I am very confused, and frankly out of ideas. Is there any thing I missed? Can anyone offer me some more ideas?

Comment: Try doing heroku-url.com/path/to/img.jpg instead of directory reference with ../img/img.jpg

Comment: Causing the same issues as the other css changes, it doesn't display locally nor in production

Comment: Oh, well sorry, don't know what to say

Answer (score 0):

In you gemfile add gem

[rails_12factor](https://github.com/heroku/rails_12factor)

Comment: Have that, but it is specified to production, will that cause issues?

Answer (score 0):

Try this ..........

By default Rails 4 will not serve your assets. To enable this functionality you need to go into config/application.rb and add this line:

```
config.serve_static_assets = true
```

Alternatively you can achieve the same result by including the rails_12factor gem in your Gemfile:

```
gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production
```

This gem will configure your application to serve static assets so that you do not need to do this manually in a config file.
Please have a look here https://github.com/heroku/rails_12factor#rails-4-serve-static-assets

Hope this will work for you.